# Is there a way to display only a certain view in the viewport?

Tags: 3d-view

What I want to do is to only display an object, or a part of an object in a specific view, and then to be able to move around the 3D workspace, with everything else hidden.

Basically, I want to display only a what a camera can see, no matter the position or perspective in the viewport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED: Go to the desired position in the 3D viewport, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, and box select around the desired area. This will make everything outside of that ray hidden:

[image]
Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> again to return to the normal 3D viewport display

Note: This can not be animated, and does not render.