# I cant see meshes in Solid and Wireframe mode but i can see it in Render mode

Tags: 3d-view

I cant see anything in Solid and Wireframe mode but everything is fine with Material preview and Render mode. Tho in Solid and Wireframe mode i can see just a small area like some ray going from abobe. I can select objects with A and move them. But they are only visible in that small area.
[image]

Comment: Hi :) Try pressing the ALT key + B  This keyboard combination toggles the Clipping to Border function. It enables you to hide all parts of the scene that are outside of the designated border. As it looks like you have done this then to unhide what was masked out use the same keyboard short-cut again: ALT + B to dis activate that border.

Comment: See the answer to this earlier post  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18965/is-there-a-way-to-display-only-a-certain-view-in-the-viewport

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.